# Proof that $L^p(\mu)$ is complete in Rudin's book (RCA)

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

[image]

My doubt is to prove just what is underlined in red. I tried two ways:

**first**

$ g_k = | f_{n_2} - f_{n_1} | + ... + | f_{n_{k+1}} - f_{n_{k}} | $ , then $ g_k^p = (| f_{n_2} - f_{n_1} | + ... + | f_{n_{k+1}} - f_{n_{k}} |)^p $

by Minkowski we have

$(\int_{X} g_k^pd\mu)^{1/p} \leq (\int_{X} | f_{n_2} - f_{n_1} |^p d\mu)^{1/p} +... + (\int_{X} | f_{n_{k+1}} - f_{n_{k}} |^p d\mu)^{1/p} $
 $ \hspace{1.6cm} \leq (\int_{X} \frac{1}{2^p} d\mu)^{1/p} +... + (\int_{X} \frac{1}{2^{kp}} d\mu)^{1/p} $

$ \hspace{1.6cm} \leq  \frac{1}{2} \mu(X)^{1/p} +... + \frac{1}{2^{k}} \mu(X)^{1/p} $

but to use the latter inequality it is necessary that $ \mu(X) < \infty $. which is not in the hypothesis.

**the second way I thought it was**

for each $i \in \{1, ..., k\}$

by Minkowski we have

$ (\int_{X} | f_{n_{i+1}} - f_{n_{i}} |^p d\mu)^{1/p} \leq  (\int_{X} | f_{n_{k+1}} |^p d\mu)^{1/p} + (\int_{X} |f_{n_{k}} |^p d\mu)^{1/p} $

but, here I can not use the inequality $|| f_{n_{i+1}} - f_{n_{i}} || < \frac{1}{2^{i}} $ to complete something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h_{i}=|f_{n_{i+1}}-f_{n_{i}}|$, then $\|h_{i}\|_{p}<2^{-i}$ and $g_{k}=h_{1}+\cdots+h_{k}$, so $\|g_{k}\|_{p}\leq\|h_{1}\|_{p}+\cdots+\|h_{k}\|_{p}<2^{-1}+\cdots+2^{-k}<2^{-1}+\cdots=1$.

Comment: Wow! it was so simple. thank you so much!